# Split or concatenate words like "kennenzulernen" or "kennen zu lernen", respectively?

Tags: spelling, compound, separable-verb

Most of the times I read

> Es freut mich, Sie **kennenzulernen**.

but a couple of times I've also read

> Es freut mich, Sie **kennen zu lernen**.

Is the latter form correct as well?

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2164/why-is-kennenlernen-written-as-compound-word

Comment: *kennenlernen* bzw. *kennenzulernen* ist die empfohlene und meiner Meinung einzig richtig Schreibweise. Leider wird seit 2006 auch die Trennung akzeptiert.

Comment: 405.000 results for ["Lernen wir uns kennen"](https://www.google.de/search?client=opera&q=%22lernen+wir+uns+kennen%22&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest) - Mir wird schlecht...

Comment: @Em1 *Im Chat kennenlernten wir uns* geht so gar nicht --> split verbs ;)

Comment: damit hab ich auch immer "Probleme", ich erinnere mich an ein Quiz zur neuen Rechtschreibung und ich meine, dass dort die richtige Antwort war es in 3 Wörtern zu schreiben.

Comment: @Takkat "Wo habt ihr euch kennengelernt? - Wir haben uns im Chat kennengelernt." I would never say: "Wir lernten uns im Chat kennen." Admittedly, in past tense it doesn't sound as bad as in present tense. And once again there are a lot of hits on Google. It though really surprises me.

Comment: http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-V/Texte/Trennbare-0n.html?MenuId=Word21130&lang=en

Comment: @Em1: Dein Sprachgefühl sagt dir also, dass man kennenlernen nur im Perfekt und irgendwelchen Infinitivkonstruktionen verwenden darf, um das "kennen" nicht vom "lernen" trennen zu müssen?

Comment: @StefanWalter So ungefähr. ;) Für mich klang, und klingt immer noch, der Satz "Lernen wir uns kennen" einfach sehr grausam. Wie angemerkt, fand ich das Beispiel "Wir lernten uns im Chat kennen" nicht mehr so schlimm und ich denke, es liegt daran, dass "kennen" und "lernen" weiter voneinander getrennt sind. No idea, why. "Ich lerne jeden Tag soviele nette Menschen kennen" klingt tatsächlich sehr angenehm für mich. Würd ich sogar sagen. Aber "Ich lerne dich kennen", da stellen sich mir die Nackenhaare hoch. Je mehr ich drüber nachdenke, ja man kann es trennen, aber sollte Vorsicht walten lassen.

Comment: Ich lerne kennen vs ich kennenlerne.....

Comment: @Em1 - Wow, I didn't know about ngram. Great tool. Thanks a bunch! And like Takkat says, this is beautiful enough to be an answer!

Comment: Note that the raise of split words in the last years is often triggered by poor spelling correction software which does not understand compound words and marks every compound word as wrong as long as it is not explicitly in the dictionary. It will always accept words when they are split as it has no clue about grammar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you can look up at [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Reform/trennung/), compounds of verbs are **separated**. But:

> Verbindungen mit *bleiben*, *lassen* an zweiter Stelle können auch zusammengeschrieben werden, wenn sie eine übertragenen[sic] (figürliche) Bedeutung haben. Dies gilt auch für *kennen lernen*.

Until 1996 the only valid spelling was the compound version. In the reform it was decided that the word had to be separated, but since the latest reform in 2006 both versions are accepted. Thus, you 'should' write *kennen lernen* but you can go with *kennenlernen* as well.

Interestingly enough, that – as shown in this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kennenlernen,kennenzulernen,kennengelernt,kennen%20zu%20lernen,kennen%20gelernt&year_start=1800&year_end=2012&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckennenlernen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckennenzulernen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckennengelernt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckennen%20zu%20lernen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckennen%20gelernt%3B%2Cc0t1;,kennenlernen;,c0;.t1;,kennenzulernen;,c0;.t1;,kennengelernt;,c0;.t1;,kennen%20zu%20lernen;,c0;.t1;,kennen%20gelernt;,c0t1;,kennenlernen;,c0;.t1;,kennenzulernen;,c0;.t1;,kennengelernt;,c0;.t1;,kennen%20zu%20lernen;,c0;.t1;,kennen%20gelernt;,c0) – until around 1910 the word was solely written separated. Only since then the word was written together. And only because of the reform in 1996 the separated version gained 'popularity' again.

Anyway. When adding the infinitive-*zu*, you consequently write *kennenzulernen* or *kennen zu lernen*. The choice is up to you.

As always, in a continuous text you should be consistent and keep to one variant.

You can take a look at the full set of rules and regulations. The respective paragraph is [§34.4 E7](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/GetrZusammen/pgf33-35.html#pgf34-E7).

---

German translation:

Wie auf [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Reform/trennung/) <strike>nach zu lesen</strike> nachzulesen ist, werden Verbindungen zweier Verben **getrennt geschrieben**. Aber:

> Verbindungen mit *bleiben*, *lassen* an zweiter Stelle können auch zusammengeschrieben werden, wenn sie eine übertragenen[sic] (figürliche) Bedeutung haben. Dies gilt auch für *kennen lernen*.

Bis zur Reform von 1996 war die zusammengeschriebene Variante die einzig gültige Schreibweise. Danach musste es getrennt geschrieben werden. Und seit 2006 ist wieder beides erlaubt. Demnach 'soll' man heutzutage also *kennen lernen* schreiben, darf aber auch die 'alte' Variante verwenden.

Interessant diesbegüglich ist, das – wie dieses [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kennenlernen,kennenzulernen,kennengelernt,kennen%20zu%20lernen,kennen%20gelernt&year_start=1800&year_end=2012&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckennenlernen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckennenzulernen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckennengelernt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckennen%20zu%20lernen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckennen%20gelernt%3B%2Cc0t1;,kennenlernen;,c0;.t1;,kennenzulernen;,c0;.t1;,kennengelernt;,c0;.t1;,kennen%20zu%20lernen;,c0;.t1;,kennen%20gelernt;,c0t1;,kennenlernen;,c0;.t1;,kennenzulernen;,c0;.t1;,kennengelernt;,c0;.t1;,kennen%20zu%20lernen;,c0;.t1;,kennen%20gelernt;,c0) zeigt – bis etwa ins Jahre 1910 das Wort bereits getrennt geschrieben wurde und erst seit dieser Zeit die zusammengeschriebene Variante vorzufinden ist. Erst durch die Rechtschreibreform 1996 hat die getrennte Schreibweise wieder an 'Popularität' dazugewonnen.

Anyway. Das bedeutet nun, wenn man das Infinitiv-*zu* hinzufügt, schreibt man entweder *kennenzulernen* oder *kennen zu lernen*. Die Wahl liegt also ganz bei dir.

Wie immer gilt aber, in einem fortlaufenden Text sollte man sich auf eine Variante festlegen.

Nachzulesen ist das ganze auch noch mal im [Regelwerk unter Paragraph §34.4 E7](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/GetrZusammen/pgf33-35.html#pgf34-E7).

Comment: Regarding the “should”, this should absolutely be read with a grain of salt. Both _Duden_ and _Wahrig_ prefer and recommend the spelling _kennenlernen_. / Was das „soll“ angeht, das darf man auf keinen Fall zu wörtlich nehmen. Sowohl _Duden_ als auch _Wahrig_ bevorzugen und empfehlen die Schreibung _kennenlernen_.

Answer (score 1):

Your example illustrates some important things about spelling rules: While they're necessary and important, they go over the top by trying to regulate even minute details, that should be matters of taste, and they are completely ahistorical (where language, incidentally, is a historical phenomenon).

If you go through the centuries, you'll find examples for both versions, and probably for a couple others. They all accurately reflect spoken language. Pronunciation does not change a bit based on whether there's an additional space or not.

It seems this is one point where I tend to agree with the horribly botched und unnecessary reform that was perpetrated a couple years ago. Frankly, an additional space or none, it shouldn't matter.

That said, »kennenlernen« as one word looks better to me, because that's what I'm used to seeing.

Answer (score -1):

I have read the answers and was astonished. I thought it would be plain wrong to take "kennenlernen" for something or "kennen lernen" for a person.

##### "kennenlernen"

- "Die werden mich noch kennenlernen." (sort of threat that someone utters in anger)
- "Wir haben uns doch noch nicht einmal richtig kennengelernt." (you would *not* say the same thing with the other two words "lieben" or "schätzen", like "Wir haben uns doch noch nicht einmal richtig lieben gelernt")
- "kennenlernen" means something like seeing each other for some time, for example in a job interview or is often called "Kennenlern-Gespräch" or over some time at the beginning of a relation, or if you chat with someone for longer, and the like.
- "Wir haben uns kennen und schätzen gelernt." or: "Ich habe diese Stadt kennen und lieben gelernt" (this is more the game with the words, like a proverb since both point at "gelernt" and you would not write "kennen- und lieben gelernt" since it is clear from the setting that kennen does not just mean "Bescheid wissen / zuordnen können", but the deepness of a relation)
- "Sich richtig kennenzulernen ist gar nicht so einfach."
- "Bewerben Sie sich gerne erneut, möglicherweise gibt es zu einem etwas späteren Zeitpunkt die Gelegenheit, sich kennenzulernen."

##### "kennen lernen"

- "Nun sind wir schon 30 Jahre verheiratet, und es vergeht kein Tag, an dem ich nicht noch neue Seiten an dir kennen lerne." (Here, it is not the person, but the many patterns of a person that I get to know; that is why you would write it with a space in between.)

##### "kennen lernen" stresses "learning", "kennenlernen" stresses the aim of getting to know a person

Taken from: https://www.studysmarter.de/schule/deutsch/rechtschreibregeln/kennenzulernen/:

> Die Getrenntschreibung "kennen zu lernen" wird oft verwendet, wenn man
> den Fokus auf das "Lernen" legen möchte. Hier liegt der Schwerpunkt
> auf dem Lernprozess.
>
> Auf der anderen Seite betont die Zusammenschreibung "kennenzulernen"
> eher das Ziel des Kennenlernens. Hier liegt der Schwerpunkt auf dem
> Ergebnis des Prozesses, nämlich dem Kennenlernen der anderen Person.
>
> Das zeigen Dir auch die folgenden Beispiele:
>
> Es freut mich sehr, Dich endlich persönlich kennenzulernen. (Fokus auf
> Kennenlernen)
>
> Während des Austauschprogramms hatte Frida die Möglichkeit, eine
> andere Kultur kennen zu lernen. (Fokus auf Lernen)

Put in English:

> The separate spelling "to get to know" is often used when you want to
> focus on "learning". Here, the emphasis is on the learning process.
>
> On the other hand, the compound spelling "kennenzulernen" tends to
> emphasise the goal of getting to know something. Here, the focus is on
> the result of the process, namely getting to know the other person.
>
> The following examples also show you that:
>
> I am very pleased to finally meet you in person. (Focus on getting to
> know each other)
>
> During the exchange programme, Frida had the opportunity to get to
> know a different culture. (Focus on learning)

#### Loss of information stands against free choice

On the whole, it seems to be a loss of information if you take "kennenlernen" and "kennen lernen" for the same thing. At least if you get to know a person, you take "kennenlernen", and you stress the first syllable. For "kennen gelernt", you may also (slightly) stress the second word, at least more than with the "kennengelernt". Which shows that this rule is not only something about writing, but also about speaking.